# How to improve simulation efficiency of method of simulated moments with random coefficient?

Tags: simulation, moments

I have a model with two layers. There are 4 variables with random coefficients in the second layer of the model, which is a multivariate Logit. I assume the four random coefficients follow multivariate normal distribution with different variances. Some of them even have nonzero co-variances.

The values generated/simulated from the second layer are going to be put in the functions in the first layer, which is a dynamic model. The moment is the difference between real data and the product of values generated from functions of both two layers.

I know direct Monte Carlo simulations do not work for this problem because the efficiency is going to be low for such a problem. It may provides poor coverage and the number of draws will have to be very large to achieve a good approximation. However, I don't think other algorithms such as MCMC can work for my problem because I have a static model with random coefficients within a dynamic model. What's more, I also have to draw another set of errors to simulate households' behavior with the simulated parameters.

I also look into Laplace approximation and also find hard to apply in my situation. I wonder how I simulate efficiently in such a problem. Thank you all!